# Is there an easy way to copy an instance of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to make a step based puzzle game (kind of like Baba Is You) and I need to store the state of the level at each step. So I'm using classes for the level, entities and some other things, and I was wondering if I can use default constructors like "Level(Level &&)" or "Level(const Level &)" I saw proposed by autocompletion to make a copy of the level as it is, but I can't grasp how they work from the documentation. The main idea was to have each level have its previous step (the copy of the level at the previous step) as an attribute, so that the game can work out any step recursively.

The question is : is any of this possible?

Because the only other way I see to do this is by making a method for my class that will simply create a new blank level and set all the attributes of this new level to those of the actual level, then return it and store it in the main scope. And this seems to be pretty bad because it requires to have evrything public or another method that sets every private attribute to a new value.

If you want to give a look at the code it's here : https://github.com/Leroymilo/SwapCpp/tree/main/Experimental but it's not really clean since I'm starting in C++, and I believe from what I know that this is more of a technical question that doesn't involve correcting what I did (hopefully).

Comment: please show a [mre] of what you've tried and what you are stuck with

Comment: It might be a better to have a stack or vector of levels, independent of the levels themselves.

Comment: If an instance of your class does not manage any resources that need to be explicitly freed, then you don't need to explicitly define a copy constructor - the compiler will implicitly define one. Right now, `Level` contains a `Grid`, and `Grid` has a pointer to a managed resource of `tiles`. It's a managed resource because you have to "clean it up" on object destruction. Right now, your implicit copy constructor for `Grid` will merely copy the pointer, and then both `Grid` objects will try to `delete` the same memory region on destruction.

Comment: I'm focusing on `Grid`, because you need to get your building blocks working before you can build a building. `Grid` does not adhere to the rule of 3: if you need one of a deconstructor, copy constructor, or copy assignment operator, then you need the others. It also does not adhere to `RAII`, which is admittedly a horrible initialization, but I didn't come up with it. Please read up on RAII and rule of 3. There's more info than I can cram in an answer. You need to get `Grid` adherent to this before you work on `Level`. This will save you time in the short-medium term.

Comment: [RAII](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#finally); [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three); https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3578.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking at this mess to point out the issue, now I know how to build my classes better, and thanks to another answer, I know how to use defaulted copy constructors to work it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use default constructors like `Level(Level &&)` or `Level(const Level &)`

- `Level(Level &&)` is the [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor). You don't want that, because you don't want to damage the original object
- `Level(Level const &)` is the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), which is for making a duplicate of an existing object without altering the original.

  This is *exactly* what you're asking for, and should be covered pretty early by any competent book in the section on writing classes.
- for reference, *"default constructor"* means specifically `Level()` - the [constructor with no arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor). This is a well-known term that should also be described in any competent book.

The compiler-generated versions of these constructors are sometimes described as *defaulted* (and can be requested like

```
Level(Level const &) = default;
```

in situations where they wouldn't be generated automatically, or just to make it explicit) - but it's important not to confuse them with the *default constructor* (which may itself be defaulted if you don't provide one).

Whether the compiler-generated copy constructor will actually do the right thing for you depends entirely on the data members and semantics of your class, which you haven't shown.

In general, it will work as a shallow copy so long as you don't use owning raw pointers or non-copyable types like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). The [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is particularly suitable for automatic shallow copying where you want shared ownership.

If you want a deep copy, you either need to write the copy constructor by hand or use (ie, find or write) a deep-copying smart pointer.

Either way, see the [Guidelines on Resource Management](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-resource) for recommendations that will help the compiler generate correct constructors and destructors for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly the type of answer I was looking for, it makes things much more clear and now I know what to clean and change thanks to another comment.